Why is the 2nd card displaying a color inconsistency with the other cards?
I cannot find the reason that the 2nd card is displaying a different color in the middle portion of the card then the outer portions. The other cards are displaying the same color consistently throughout the entire card. I want the color to be hsl(0, 0%, 10%). Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?


#projectsWrapper{
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 15%);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 600px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
  padding: 80px 0;
}
.projectsCont{
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: none;
}
.container * {
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 24px;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-padding-top: 24px;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
.container .card {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  margin-left: 90px;
}
.container .card3{
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-right: 110px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
<div id="projectsWrapper" class="container scroll-1">
    <div class="projectsCont card" style="background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);">

    </div>
    <div class="projectsCont card" style="background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);">

    </div>
    <div class="projectsCont card3" style="background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);">

    </div>
  </div>




They are all displaying properly for me. https://codepen.io/jaytb95/pen/wvLommZ

on the display, it is still showing a slight discoloration in the center of the card, it can be easily missed but it still shows differently. Can you please try checking again?

They are all rendering with the same color, both visually and according to Chrome's developer tools.

The code displays them all the same and on my device every card shows the same. It sounds like a display issue on your device.

I am using macOS, can that be related to the issue?

The issue happened to be the way the color was determined. The hsl values outputted different colors. I used a HEX color code instead of hsl values which is more precise and it solved my problem of color inconsistency. Thanks everyone for your contributions to my question.
